# How to determine the type of JsonPrimitive

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to determine the type of my JsonPrimitive object. For example:

```
if (jsonPrimitive.isNumber()) {
   Number number = jsonPrimitive.getAsNumber();
   ....
}
```

The type of number is Number since the following is true:

```
(number instanceof Number)
```

However the following is wrong:

```
(number instanceof Integer)
```

and of course the underlying value is integer (for example - 5).
I would like to be able to return the correct object from my method.
Thanks!

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: `Number` is abstract so, the real class of number variable should be one of: `Integer`, `Long`, `BigInteger`, I doubt your library needs/has custom implementations of `Number`. Did you try with `instanceof Long` or maybe `instanceof BigInteger`?

Comment: yes. I have tried that and it doesn't work :\ I'm using gson 2.0.2

Comment: You do the `instanceof Integer` test inside the `if (jsonPrimitive.isNumber())` block? Should work if the test succeeds: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/tags/gson-2.0/src/main/java/com/google/gson/JsonPrimitive.java. See lines 140 and 150.